# SQL not selecting multiple rows based on a value in one of them

Tags: sql-server

Difficult one to explain this. I am trying to get a count of new memberships which should be easy enough as I just select on the join date. However, due to the design of the database, it is picking up membership conversions which I do not want to include. The only way to find if it is a conversion or not is to look in a table called History actions which will have a void transaction in it. So currently my data looks a bit like this

```
Date        Name        History Action

1/1/2014    Fred Bloggs Added

1/1/2014    Joe Bloggs  Added

1/1/2014    Joe Bloggs  Void

1/1/2014    John Doe    Added

2/1/2014    Jane Doe    Added

2/1/2014    Jane Doe    Void
```

From this, I only want the rows for Fred Bloggs and John Doe as they are new memberships. Joe Bloggs and Jane Doe were conversions of old memberships and not new sales so should not be included.

How do I tell SQL not to select any of the Joe Bloggs or Jane Doe records because one of them is Void? If I just say where != Void then it will still leave the Added record which will count as a new sale where it is not.

There is a lot more data than this spread across several tables but this gives the general idea. From the example fields, the first two fields are in one table and the History Action is in a separate table linked by an inner join and is the table that causes multiple rows for the same person.

Any hints gratefully accepted!

Comment: What is your current query. Post it here

Comment: This could work: select name from history h where h.action='Added' and (select count(*) from history where name = h.name) = 1

Comment: Thanks everyone for their help. Can't post the query due to my low rep but it now seems to be fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE Name NOT IN (SELECT Name FROM table WHERE Action = 'Void')
```

But its not cool to do it like this, because you can have same names, so use some user id field instead of Name.

Comment: This sounds like a good option - I'll give it a go and let you know. Many thanks. If I get stuck, I will post the whole query but it is quite complex.

Comment: This seems to have worked perfectly - after I spotted that I was searching for VOIDED instead of VOID. I'll post my complete query below. Thanks everyone for your advice. Just sorry I can't vote you up as it is my first post.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this

```
SELECT Name
  FROM HistoryActions
 GROUP BY Name
HAVING MAX(CASE WHEN HistoryAction = 'Added' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0
   AND MAX(CASE WHEN HistoryAction = 'Void' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 0
```

or

```
SELECT Name
  FROM HistoryActions h
 WHERE NOT EXISTS
(
  SELECT *
    FROM HistoryActions
   WHERE Name = h.Name
     AND HistoryAction = 'Void'
)
```

Output:

```
|        NAME |
|-------------|
| Fred Bloggs |
|    John Doe |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7815c/7)** demo

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this also...

```
SELECT * FROM YourTable WHERE Name NOT IN (SELECT Name FROM YourTable WHERE UPPER(Action) = 'VOID')
```